# Term for the opposite of salami publishing

Tags: publications, terminology

#### Question

*Salami publishing* refers to the practice of splitting scientific work into overly small pieces (least publishable units) and publishing a separate paper about each.

I am looking for a term for the opposite practice, i.e., lumping together a lot of or too much scientific work into one paper.

- I prefer terms that can be understood (by a suitable audience) without further explanation. Essentially, I want something less cumbersome than *opposite of salami publishing.*
- I have no strong preference regarding the tone of the term. E.g., it can be derogatory (but doesn’t need to be).
- I am open to neologisms, but please consider the first point.

#### Background

This term would be useful for me to talk about the publishing culture in biology (or certain subfields thereof), where new relevant methods often do not get papers on their own, but are only published as the appendix to some paper that is primarily about findings achieved with that method.

Comment: "Hot mess" as in everything is chucked in and cooked...

Comment: Isn't a sausage the food where you cram as much bits and pieces as you can in an artificial intestine?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Right. The reason for the term in use here is that it was originally "salami slicing", referring to slicing the research into as tiny pieces as possible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I know, I was making a joke :(

Comment: That's strange, Imo presenting a new method and applying it to a problem is a much better way than splitting it into just method and then application. That's a much more "round" package and pretty much standard in chemistry. I cannot see anything strange or wrong with this. WOuld be different if the authors would include several other methods too.

Comment: @DSVA: This is not a good place to have a debate about whether this is actually a good or a bad thing (I will ping you in chat). However, in some other fields, papers which focus on a method (which doesn’t mean no application) are pretty common and nobody would accuse them of salami publishing.

Comment: The term used (at least in Germany) for _combining_ a PhD thesis from multiple papers is a _cumulative thesis_.

Comment: If "salami-slicing" is cutting work into many small papers, perhaps "sausage-making" is the opposite? ;-)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I just wanted to point out that your example of "too much in one paper" is a standard thing in some fields and is seen as the correct thing to do by most of the scientists in that field.

Comment: In many fields, I believe the appropriate term is “book”.

Comment: “Gaussian”, as per his personal motto: pauca sed matura ("few, but ripe").

Comment: Whatever it's called, it may be widely deterred by the risk of exceeding a journal's length limit and incurring page charges, even from a journal where authors don't normally have to pay.

Comment: @EdV Ah, that explains the line in the Robert Redford movie _Sneakers_, 'a breakthrough of Gaussian proportions'.

Answer (score 13):

I call it "kitchen sink publishing."  I apply the term to papers which contain redundant methods for determining the result.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everything_but_the_kitchen_sink

Answer (score 11):

I had a mentor who did this a lot and I referred to it as "Magnum Opus Publishing", where the objective is to have a singular publication of such heartbreaking insight and magnitude that it encapsulates an entire research question in a single work.

Comment: Arguably, a "salami" publication can encapsulate an entire research question, too. The research question might be narrower in scope.

Answer (score 8):

I propose **smorgasbord publishing**.

Merriam-Webster [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smorgasbord) *smorgasbord* as:

> 1. a luncheon or supper buffet offering a variety of foods and dishes (such as hors d'oeuvres, hot and cold meats, smoked and pickled fish, cheeses, salads, and relishes)
> 2. an often large heterogeneous mixture : mélange

Seems appropriate.

Comment: Or of course the more "original" smörgåsbord (waiting for audio samples of people trying to pronounce it...).

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: This answer is full of tongue-in-cheek neologisms ;-)*

I would like to stay in the context of food and suggest

**Gluttony publishing** (more derogatory)

or

**Banquet publishing** (less derogatory).

You could even go as far as labeling the publication itself as banquet as in the following sentence.

> He has just written a *banquet paper* of 40 pages. He could have easily salami sliced it into 5 papers. Doesn't he know that for most grants only the number of publications counts?

A slightly different term would be a *buffet paper* denoting a paper that is a collection of not necessarily tightly coupled topics where everyone can pick what he likes. It can also refer to [a paper that is written to suit everybody](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/114402/61201).

Comment: I left mine as a comment :) but yes there are relevant terms...

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you mean by "opposite". If you treat "salami publishing" as an extreme, then the more ordinary case (by far) is just "publishing". It needs no adjective.

However, if you mean the opposite extreme, consider the following. Sometimes a field will have a period of intense work with a large number of (possibly) relatively small results. After that period ends or at least the rate of advancement slows, someone may decide to "consolidate" what has been recently learned in a summative paper that will have many references and a new top-level view of the field as it is then known. "Consolidation" and "Unification" are good terms for that sort of publication. Such a publication is a great resource for new researchers in the field (say, new PhD students).

However, if you require a food metaphor, try paella. Of course it is best savored in Andalusia. And I guess that if you need an explanation about why this is a good metaphor you haven't tried to make (or eat) it.

Answer (score 3):

A term with the positive connotation of completeness: All-in-one-publication.

A term with a slightly negative connotation of "good, but too much": The paper is an embarrassment of riches.

A term with a negative connotation: Overkill publication.

Answer (score 1):

I usually call these papers "book" or "tome", which conveys that they are way too long (at least when you look at the page count when the supplement(s) are included). The more technical criticism that too many things were lumped together there is kind of implicit, though. (These terms also apply only to the papers themselves, and not the publishing style.)

Edit: if you want to stay in the culinary realm, maybe "casserole publishing"?

Answer (score 0):

Would 'syncretic publishing' come close? Syncretic is generally used in religious studies to denote a mixture of different faiths/traditions in an unstructured manner. The structured version of this would be 'synthesis'.

Religious connotation aside, syncretic is a legitimate philosophical idea by itself. I haven't found an instance of it being used to describe academic publishing though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not think that *syncretic* or *synthetic* would be easily understood as you intend. Without any context, the first thought that comes to my mind is that this is about an interdisciplinary paper.

Comment: Hmm, interdisciplinary is a fair interpretation. Hope you find something less ambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the other answers are better than mine, but while *holistic approach* doesn't work grammatically for this purpose, could *holistic publishing* work?

For *holistric* Google returns:

> characterized by the belief that the parts of something are intimately interconnected and explicable only by reference to the whole.

If holistic publishing is the style that a person with a holistic approach to their research and their way of communicating and teaching and writing works for publication, then perhaps they can be said to be a holistic publisher.

Comment: There is a non-zero chance you have a German cultural background. While holistic in german is seen as the google result you get, in the anglo-saxon culture holistic generally means homeopathic treatment, lunar cycles in agriculture and to cut your hair and so on...

Comment: @EarlGrey that might be the first thing that pops into their minds if presented with the word holistic in some *word association game,* but used in a specific context don't you think most English speaking folk will be aware that the word has more than one meaning (as words so often do) and that they should refer to the sentence in which it was used? That's how I learned English back when I was in the mid-single digits.

Comment: I am quite sure that in a specific context there are other words than *holistic* to describe a complete overview of the complex system/topic under analysis and this is the reason why holistic has such a bad reputation.
See for example the abstract of this paper, related to biology
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3067528/

I am saying all this because a language is not what you studied in mid-single digits, it is what and how it is used by the median of the population today.

Comment: @EarlGrey being profoundly median myself, I feel I have a good finger on the pulse of the median population, unlike those with *advanced knowledge of etymology* who look down on it like so many ants the same way that entomologists look down on a colony of  *ents.*

Comment: You are as much median as much as humble!

Comment: @EarlGrey basically I don't think we should be afraid of using a word because there exist some biologists that get it wrong some of the time. Imagine if physicians fled patients who were sick rather than rallied to their side for assistance and revitalization. The word fits. It works. Let's defend the languafe! We shouldn't let a few [malapropicists](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83235/217285) kill it!

Comment: O the contrary, languages are fluid, if the perceived meaning of a word is constantly different than the one advocated by a single person, that single person will soon be Miss Malaprop. The physician will be more helpful if he/she/it uses non-ambiguous technical worlds, rather than words having a certain meaning in the dictionary and another in daily life (which most likely will end in the dictionary in one decade or so).

Comment: @EarlGrey as a fluid, I think we should encourage language to emulate water, as in Bruce Lee's *Be like water* [1](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [2](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/17472/11327) rather than become simply *[wishy-washy](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/161568/217285)* and let the  malapropicists  have their way with it.